# Connect to one WIFI via wpa_supplicant works but not to any other one (Pi Zero W)

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-zero-w

For an application on my Raspberry Pi Zero W I need WIFI access.
Developing at home worked great, but when I try to connect to any other WIFI network than my home WIFI I just cannot establish any internet connection.

Following several tutorials I did the initial configuration on the headless system via the wpa_supplicant.conf looking like this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=DE

network={
    ssid="MYSSID"
    psk="MYPW"
   key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

I also set a static IP in my dhcpcd.conv via

```
interface wlan0
inform 192.168.0.100
```

When I now edit ssid and psk in the file to use some other WIFI the connection cannot be established.
I test this via ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) which returns "temporary failure in name resolution". Switching back to the original WIFI credentials afterwards and the ping works fine again.
I also tried adding the google-nameserver 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4 to the /etc/resolv.conf without any impact.

FYI: /etc/os-release tells me "Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
I tried "normal" routers as well as laptop or mobile hotspots. None work.
I do not use any fancy network-software like pihole or anything alike just the plain default configuration.
Does not matter weather i just reboot after wpa_supplicant change or use wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure.

Any hints on what else to try?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Are you sure the static IP address is valid in the other networks? Have you tried using DHCP

Comment: Why are you trying to set a "static IP"? What you have will NOT. Get rid of the inform and let the router do the work. While many routers use 192.168 very many (including mine) do not.

Comment: I use the static IP to connect via ssh for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of connection to multiple networks just add multiple network={} stanzas. Mine has 12. You can also assign priority to each network.

See **Networking Files** in [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)